# M/S determination during OSPF database exchange

Tags: routes, ospf

As per the OSPF RFC 2328, Master/Slave determination during state ExStart of the neighbor state machine uses the Router ID to determine who becomes master and who becomes slave for the Database Exchange process. What I fail to understand (and cannot see it explained in the RFC) is why this M/S determination is needed at all given the fact that Router IDs are already known during the Hello exchange between the 2 routers. So, based on the Hello exchange, the 2 routers should know apriori who will be the master and accordingly proceed with the DB exchange directly, instead of requiring an explicit M/S determination during the ExStart state.
Can anyone help in resolving this doubt?

TIA,
RevK

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure that exchange or synchronization is reliable, ospf adopts the strategy like TCP, but more simple.
In fact, the main purpose to negotiate Master/Slave is to determine to use which sequence number. Only Master can increase the sequence number, while Slave use the same sequnce number to acknowledge Master.  if Master don't recevie the acknowledgement, it retransmit the packet. 
if Slave receive the duplicate packet form master, it retransmit the last packet to acknowledge Master.

besides, negotiation also include interface MTU.